# How to replace gzip with pigz without breaking anything

Tags: gzip

I would like to use pigz to compress my backups instead of gzip on Linux. Since pigz is a replacement for gzip, is it safe to replace the gzip binary (without deleting it) with a symlink to the pigz binary?

Could this break something on the OS?

Answer (score 4):

Better method: Tell your backup solution to use `pigz` instead.

Don't try to replace it this way. This might break other things that rely on `gzip` actually being `gzip` (unless the `pigz` developer actually has written it as a 100% full replacement with all options and behaviours intact). Also, after the next update of the package containing `gzip`, this will either replace it back to the OS version or break the update process.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. `pigz` is nearly a a drop-in replacement for `gzip`. As always, you *must* test your restores, especially because you changed something.

"Replacement" can be a symlink earlier in $PATH. The previous  `gunzip` is still available with the full path: `/usr/bin/gzip`.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/pigz /usr/local/bin/gzip
ln -s /usr/bin/unpigz /usr/local/bin/gunzip
```

Parallelism is not magic, there are limits. Note what the manual says about decompression being sequential and limited in the number of thread.

---

If zlib compatible output is not a requirement, consider evaluating other algorithms. [Zstd](http://www.zstd.net/) for example, can be tuned to a very wide range of speed versus compression. Also can be built to support multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it that way - it's unlikely in the extreme that pigz is a 100% emulation of gzip in every respect - it's bound to do a few things different beyond it's stated intent of being faster by being parallel. If you do what you suggest, everything that uses gzip (and there's no good way to know what that all is) is going to break.

Comment: pigz is written by the same person as zlib, you can bet on it being correct - https://zlib.net/pigz